# customize the "authordate1" bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies

Does anyone know how to customize `authordate1` style in such a way that the reference to pages is preceded by a full stop instead of a comma? Basically what I want is the following:

> Iverson, Gregory K. 1989. On the category supralaryngeal. *Phonology* 6. 285-303.
>
> Lahiri, Aditi (ed.). 2000. *Analogy, leveling, markedness: Principles of change in phonology and morphology (Trends in Linguistics 127)*. Berlin: Mouton de Gruyter.
>
> McCarthy, John J. & Alan S. Prince. 1999. Prosodic morphology. In John A. Goldsmith (ed.), *Phonological theory: The essential readings*. 238-288. Malden, MA & Oxford: Blackwell.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to make the change just for entries of type `@article`? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico: no I am looking to changes for all references. The page notation should just be preceded by a full stop rather than a comma.

Comment: Which other entry types feature both volume numbers and page numbers?

Comment: @Mico: please look at the edits I made in the original question.

Comment: What's the entry type of the McCarthy and Prince publication?

Comment: Assuming the McCarthy-Prince entry has type `@incollection`, the excerpt you posted above doesn't look like it was formatted by the `authordate1` bibliography style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're looking to make this change just for entries of type `@article`. (At least, I don't know of other entry types that feature both `volume` and `pages` fields.) If that's the case, you could proceed as follows.

- Locate the file `authordate1.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file -- don't edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly! -- and name the copy, say, `authordate1dot.bst`.
- Open the file `authordate1dot.bst` in a text editor. The editor you use for your tex files will do fine.
- Inside `authordate1dot.bst`, locate the function called `format.vol.num.date.pages`. In my copy of the bst file, this function starts at line 477, and it spans about 30 lines.
- Toward the end of the `format.vol.num.date.pages` code block, locate the following line:

  ```
          { ", " * pages n.dashify * }
  ```

  Change the comma to a full stop. The line should thus look like this:

  ```
          { ". " * pages n.dashify * }
  ```
- Save the file `authordate1dot.bst`, either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to also update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{authordate1}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{authordate1dot}
  ```

  and run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!